# How to include <li> elements with textNode without using innerHTML or jQuery

Tags: javascript, dom

Insert this structure inside the body tag without using innerHTML and use a FOR loop for the 3 li elements :

```
<div id="divEx1">
    <p>Langages basés sur ECMAScript :</p>
    <ul>
        <li>JavaScript</li>
        <li>JScript</li>
        <li>ActionScript</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I already created the elements

with is text node and the ul element, but I have trouble with the li elements. I added a document.createElement("li") in a variable named eLi, then  I created a loop  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) with a document.querySelector("ul").appenChild(eLi), a switch for putting the appropriate document.createTextNode() in a varaible named texteLi and finally a document.querySelector("li").appendChild(texteLi)

```
var eLi = document.createElement("li");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
document.querySelector("ul").appendChild(eLi);
switch (i) {
    case 1:
        texteLi = document.createTextNode("Javascript");
    case 2:
        texteLi = document.createTextNode("JScript");
    case 3:
        texteLi = document.createTextNode("Actionscript");

    document.querySelector("li").appendChild(texteLi);
}
}
```

Here is my result :

https://ibb.co/Kj5PGKF

I don't understand why there is a CSS pseudo-class ::marker

Comment: It's always better to fix known bugs before trying to explain bad output. Three issues require changes: the code only creates one **LI** element (element creation needs to go inside the loop), the `switch` statement is missing `break` statements and so each case just flows into the next one, and inserting the text element should be outside the `switch` statement. Consider putting the text strings in an array and  doing away with the `switch` statement anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start first with breaks. I think you need to put `break;` at the end of every case, i have had problems with not putting it in the past, plus it helps in making reading your code logic for debugging.

Next, if I am correct, This code will always only create one node because `document.querySelector("li").appendChild(texteLi)` is placed in case:3

Last I think you should start your cases at 0 and not 1 because you have `i < 3` instead of `i <= 3` and I dont see how case 3 is executing

I dont think I have really answered the question you asked but I think these might be some of the problems

Comment: There's no "think" about it. You have to put a break statement after each `case` otherwise the code will fall through to the next `case`

Answer (score 0):

To set the content of a node without using innerHTML `node.textContent = text`

Answer (score 0):

You have the correct approach, but you are not creating 3 `<li>` elements in your code above, rather only one. Also, you are querying the `<ul>` in each iteration of the loop, which you don't need to do. Further, using a switch statement here might seem handy, but your syntax is wrong and there is a better way. Since you are already using a for-loop, let's just iterate over an array of your desired text content and use the index to inject our text. Keeping with your code-style, the resulting code might look something like this:

```
var textArray = ["Javascript","JScript","Actionscript"]    
var eU = document.querySelector("ul")
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var eLi = document.createElement("li")
  var textNode =  document.createTextNode(textArray[i]);
  eLi.appendChild(textNode)
  eU.appendChild(eLi)
}
```

Try it out in your console but creating the `<ul>` instead of selecting it, and you will see your desired result:

```
var textArray = ["Javascript","JScript","Actionscript"]    
var eU = document.createElement("ul")
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var eLi = document.createElement("li")
  var textNode =  document.createTextNode(textArray[i]);
  eLi.appendChild(textNode)
  eU.appendChild(eLi)
}
console.log(eU)
```